# Badge for general sharing on Social Media

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I frequently promote questions and the homepage of a couple SE sites that are still in beta. Since these sites are new and I don't have a huge following, I am unlikely to get an Announcer badge for driving a lot of traffic to a single question, but I am getting a lot of people to visit the sites across a lot of different questions.

Can I get a badge, for getting people to visit the site even if they are looking at different questions? I think this would be especially beneficial on a beta sites.

In other words, total all the views on a site that come from my efforts to promote the site (using the user id in the url that SE already adds to shared links). When that total reaches 200, award a bronze. Silver could be 2k and gold 20k.

Comment: Hmm, how should this badge be awarded? "many different questions" is terribly non-descriptive.

Comment: SE adds your user idea to links to questions you share. It would need to add the user id when your are sharing any other page on the site as well.

Comment: In my opinion, only viewing won't be enough. Only if enough users who followed your links actually created an account, the badge would be given.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I really like that idea!

Comment: Cheers @Luke, and the badge can be called "Missionary". ;)